# Parallel AsyncTask execution state

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

How can I ensure that all my asynctask running in parallel have finished executing? I am running several asynctasks in parallel using executer.
Need to know that all have finished their task.

Comment: How are you getting notified that any of your asyncTask has finished its work?

Comment: why are you doing this, can you please explain  this.

Comment: I have one async which checks for certain condition. Based on condition i have to download some files in parallel. These parallel download is started from with in first async. Now i have 3-4 asyncs running in parallel from the firat one. How can ensure all of these asyncs have finished their execution? I want to do remaining work in first async after all have executed.

Comment: You have to see through the size of `ThreadPool` that you are using, you might get an Error for executing more threads than the capacity of your ThreadPool. Cheers.

Comment: I am using default Thread pool executer in Android

Comment: Then, you should check it's size first before executing too many AsyncTasks. or you can create your own ThreadPool Executor with a specific capacity and then use it to execute your AsyncTasks.

Comment: Can I get some code example of creating one in Android? And then check its size to ensure execution finishing?

Comment: The intteger method worked.. But do I need to synchronize the threads? If yes how? And will it create any issue in parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to track each `AsyncTask` in a `List` or `Map` of some kind.  When they finish, have them remove themselves from the tracker (within `onPostExecute()`).  When all have been removed, they are all done.  Be careful with these as well as other threading techniques: they are not Android component (`Activity`, `Service`) lifecycle aware.

Comment: You mean to say.. Start them and put them in list and do while(!listIsEmpty) keep waiting.. ?

Comment: No, you should not wait like this. They are asynchronous  and if you wait and block your app will get killed.

Comment: I don't think so.. I am starting parallel threads from another asynctask's doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution You can use an int class variable like this:

```
private int TOTAL_ASYNC_TASKS_IN_PROGRESS = 0;
```

then increment this int in the `onPreExecute()` method and decrement this int in `onPostExecute()` method.

When you will have this int value = 0, then it means that all your AsyncTasks has been Executed.

**Edit:**: 
You should use your own implementation of ThreadPool Executor and execute the AsyncTasks with your ThreadPool executor instead of the default one. Because by using the default provided ThreadPool Executor you may run out of capacity while Executing too many Multiple AsyncTasks.

Here is a nice tutorial for implementing a Custom ThreadPool Executor: 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/my-custom-thread-pool-executor-in-java.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is this the right way? This is the first thought I got to resolve the situation  ;)

Comment: It seems to be a way of doing it, am not sure if it's the right way. But it will surely solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this. Is there a best practice for running async in parallel or a custom way of executing in parallel?